# My entire screen goes grey when I am in the camera view and press P to start game

Tags: camera

Whenever I start my blender game (press P) while looking through the first person camera, the screen just goes gray. I've tried everything I could find, changing the cameras zoom/focus/clipping. I've deleted the camera and added a new one and still have this problem. I don't think it has to do with it not at the right criteria because the view works fine while not in game mode but as soon as I switch to it, it goes grey.

The pictures are when I am in camera view before pressing P and after.
[image: I attached a picture of the view before I press P.]

[image: When I press P]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is shown if you go into textured mode and enable render only in the viewport?

Comment: Try to attach your file, that will help you get better answers.

Comment: @HenrikD I also get the view similar to the first image, for some reason its only when I start the game

Comment: @Georges Im not sure how to attach the file, there doesnt seem to be the option

Comment: @christmaseveryday22 you can upload it here, remember to copy the link and add it to your question: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Comment: @Georges okay here is the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fNICaDzJN7AKcRe1xWHWbNAlGAi28TxK/view?usp=sharing